# HTML5 Everything disappears after clicking a button

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm new to html5.
I'm not sure what happened here, I'm trying to make it so whenever the button is clicked, a quadratic function appears in the canvas. But in what I wrote, whenever I click the button everything disappears right after actually plotting the requested curve.
Here's the code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jumping_cat/xc0L60k1/1/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
<form action="">
a: <input type="text" name="tbax2" id="itbax2" value=0.01 size="4">
b: <input type="text" name="tbbx" id="itbbx" value=1 size="4">
c: <input type="text" name="tbc" id="itbc" value=40 size="4">
<button onclick="dibujarCurva()">Graficar</button>

</form>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="300"
style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
function dibujarCurva(){
 var ax2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('itbax2').value);
 var bx = parseFloat(document.getElementById('itbbx').value);
 var c = parseFloat(document.getElementById('itbc').value);
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.strokeStyle = '#FF0000'
 x=0
 ctx.moveTo(0,150-(ax2*(x-250)*(x-250) + bx*(x-250) + c));
 while (x<501){
  ctx.lineTo(x,150-(ax2*(x-250)*(x-250) + bx*(x-250) + c));
  x=x+10
  ctx.stroke();}
  ctx.closePath();
 }
function dibujarGrid(){
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.strokeStyle = '#F2F2F2'
 ctx.moveTo(0,0);
 x=0
 while (x<501){
  ctx.moveTo(x,0);
  ctx.lineTo(x,300);
  x=x+10
  ctx.stroke();}
 x=0
 while (x<301){
  ctx.moveTo(0,x);
  ctx.lineTo(500,x);
  x=x+10
  ctx.stroke();}
 ctx.closePath();
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000'
 ctx.moveTo(250,0);
 ctx.lineTo(250,300);
 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.moveTo(0,150);
 ctx.lineTo(500,150);
 ctx.stroke();
 }
 dibujarGrid()
 ctx.fillText(("ax^2 + bx + c"),10,20);
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be trying to submit the form.
A quick and easy fix is to change your onclick as follows:

```
<button onclick="return dibujarCurva()">Graficar</button>
```

and add a

```
return false;
```

to the end of the dibujarCurva() function.

This is useful if you want to conditionally submit. However, as slicedtoad and acontell pointed out the following will also solve it without any modification to the function.

```
<button type="button" onclick="dibujarCurva()">Graficar</button>
```

Comment: Or add `type="button"` to the button element.

Comment: Also another totally valid option. Editing it in for completeness.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the type attribute of the button and prevent it from sending the form:

```
<button type="button" onclick="dibujarCurva()">Graficar</button>
```